# Unit Testing: How to test a method returning current time

Tags: c++, unit-testing, epoch

Suppose that I've got a method called `Now` which should return the current time in epoch format (in milliseconds) once called. Is it possible to test if such method is returning the correct value? Does testing such method make sense at all?

Comment: Which testing method would you use?

Comment: how are you getting the current time?

Comment: @Yannbane I'm using boost test library.

Comment: Use other time getting methods (before and after) to test accuracy.  Call it a bunch of times in a loop to make sure it is as granular as you hope.

Comment: @Yakk, I think your method will work, but it's a bit of a workaround. If you ask me, the best way to go about it would be to interact with the mechanism that gets that time.

Comment: @Yakk: Proper unit tests should be deterministic. They shouldn't succeed or fail "most of the time", but always return the same result when running the same code with the same test data. Otherwise you will have people who don't care when tests fail, because "well, they fail from time to time" and your software quality goes downhill.

Comment: @Philipp, sure.  But there is a huge difference between false positives and false negatives.  Your concern -- that they "fail from time to time" -- is caused by false failures.  While false test passes are less than ideal, a unit test that can catch an error that would be a problem (but doesn't always catch it) is better than no test at all: perfection is the enemy of the good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is very likely just a wrapper around a call to the standard library. The standard library doesn't need any testing. All you need to test is the code which takes something from the standard library and transforms it into the format you need. So I would suggest you to move this code to a separate method and test it by not feeding it the current value returned from the standard library, but fixed values with known correct results.